# Firefox not recognizing a link registered by the vue eventhandler in older Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, firefox

I do have a following HTML code:

```
<button id="btncontinue" ref="btncontinue" v-on:click="oncontinueclick" v-show="continuevisible">
<i class="fa fa-arrow-alt-circle-right fa-2x continue-icon"  v-show="continuevisible"></i>
</button>
```

oncontinueclick fires registered method in the vue app. It works fine in the last browsers.
However, there is an odd problem with older browsers. I have to make it work for FF 45.9 and newer.
On FF 52 i experienced following problem - there are no script errors, but the button itself is not clickable (It's not even showing a hand cursor like on FF 7x, icon and the button are just the part of the background). It's like the eventhandler is not recognized, but in the inspector i see events attached, they even redirect to vue invoker, so it seems that FF has no problems with the scripts.

[image]

`<i>` element wasn't originally clickable, i just made it so for tests purposes. Is there any workaround? Or is this simply my error?

Vue version: 2.6.11 (but also 2.5.13)
There a bootstrap linked (without js)
and Axios (0.19.2)

Comment: Isnt oncontinueclick triggered twice, on the button and on <i>

Comment: Yes, now yes, but i added it later just to test if this changes anything. Originally <i> element had no events, just on the button, sorry for the confusion. I corrected it so it's clear now.

Comment: Nevermind, the problem was with the z-order, nothing to do with scripts, just the older browser differently interpreted some css settings and the button was covered by the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, the problem was with the z-order, nothing to do with scripts, just the older browser differently interpreted some css settings and the button was covered by the input.